RLS Not Applying to Visuals Using Calculated Table in Power BI
`I have implemented Row-Level Security (RLS) in my Power BI data model. While it works for most visuals, it does not apply to visuals that use a column from a specific calculated table. The calculated table was created using calculated table.
If I apply a slicer using the same column used in the RLS, the visuals work correctly, so it seems like the relationships are set up properly.
To verify the relationships, I created a slicer with the column used in RLS. When I interact with the slicer, all visuals behave as expected, confirming that there’s no issue with the relationships.
However, RLS is still not applying to visuals that depend on the calculated table above.`

This question is similar to: Apply RLS to a calculated table. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
